Is there a way to disallow Mediawiki users to edit any User: page?
I want to disallow that my registered Mediawiki users are able to modify their User page.
Anything else should be editable by default as usual.

Try: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Lockdown . This extension implements a way to restrict access to specific namespaces and special pages to a given set of user groups. That said, the MediaWiki framework itself is not build for restrictions. However that extension does seem to do the trick.
